# Как сделать что б при открытии balloon в api yandex map не исчезал Placemark?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, frontend

```js
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([48.480223, 135.071917], {
            // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.
            balloonContentBody: "<div class='ballon-body'><div class='ballon-ttl'>ОАО “Аквапарк Хабаровск”</div><div class='ballon-more' data-more='1'>Подробнее</div><div class='ballon-img'><img src='static/imgs/ballon-img.png'></div></div>",
      
         }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'static/imgs/placeholder.png',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [50, 64],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

За это отвечает опция hideIconOnBalloonOpen https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/#Placemark__param-options.hideIconOnBalloonOpen